# Condition for an operator on a bounded geometry manifold to be represented by a Schwartz kernel

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, operator-theory, riemannian-geometry, sobolev-spaces

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold with bounded geometry, which means that:

- the injectivity radius is positive;
- for each $l$, there exists $C_l>0$ such that $||\nabla^l R||\leq C_l$, where $R$ is the Riemann curvature tensor and the norm is taken fibrewise.

Let $T:L^2(M)\rightarrow L^2(M)$ be a bounded operator.

**Question 1:** Is there a general criterion for this type of setting that says when $T$ is given by a continuous Schwartz kernel $k_T:M\times M\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$?

**Question 2:** In particular, suppose for every $i\geq 0$ that $T$ maps from $H^i(M)$ to $C^\infty(M)$. Is this enough to guarantee the existence and continuity of $k_T$? Here $H^i(M)$ denotes the $i$-th Sobolev space on $M$.

Comment: I assume you want non compact manifolds? Otherwise the condition on bounded geometry is trivially satisfied, although I am not sure what the answer to your questions is in the compact case either.

Comment: Yes, indeed I'm only thinking about non-compact manifolds. I have a suspicion the answer to question 2 might be positive even if one removes the bounded geometry condition.

Comment: Are the answers yes for compact manifold?

Comment: @ArcticChar For example, I think on a compact manifold any pseudodifferential operator of sufficiently large negative order (determined by the dimension of the manifold) has a continuous kernel. And the answer to the second question is yes I believe.